# Access to Jira Accouncement Banners in Remote API

Tags: jira-rest-api

I'm working on an application that has tight integration with our Jira instance, but has completely separate pages. We have some Jira maintenance coming up and I wanted to be able to retrieve any current Jira Announcement banners that are being displayed and pull them into these stand-alone pages.

I looked through the API documentation and I couldn't find anything that would point to being able to load this data, but I wanted to see if anyone had figured out how to do this. I am running Jira 6.1 and using the REST API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of JIRA 6.3.11, REST API version 2, it can't be done.

You can read some folks asking about similar functions here:
https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/70345

Here's a link to the JIRA REST API docs:
https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/

At present, the only method I know of for reading the content of the announcement banner would be to read it from the database.  I'm using PostgreSQL and would use this:

```
SELECT pt.propertyvalue
  FROM propertytext pt JOIN propertyentry pe
  ON pt.id=pe.id
  WHERE pe.property_key='jira.alertheader';
```

Comment: I agree. In all of the searching I did, I couldn't find a way to do this without connecting to the API directly. Thanks for confirming my findings.